# System path check has TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, path, nltk, system, pipenv

## Goal: To import files in a pretty manner

I have a piece of code (See Source) that attempts to load environment data (from a `.env` file) and then adding a specific configuration value to the system path. This supposedly enables me to import other files with the following format:

```
from evaluation.word_probability import WordFrequencyCounter
```

This allows me access a `word_probability.py` Python file from the `evaluation` folder using this notation, as seen in the last line of the source code below:

### Source

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from os import environ

# Add python project root folder to python path
load_dotenv(find_dotenv(), override=True, verbose=False)
PYTHON_SCRIPTS_DIR = environ.get('PYTHON_SCRIPTS_DIR')
PROJECT_DIR = environ.get('PROJECT_DIR')
sys.path.insert(0, PYTHON_SCRIPTS_DIR)

from evaluation.word_probability import WordFrequencyCounter
```

## The problem

The problem I'm encountering is that when I run my python script, it tells me that it could not iterate on a `NoneType`:

#### Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/word_frequencies.py", line 13, in <module>
    from evaluation.word_probability import WordFrequencyCounter
  File "/Users/darrenkarlsapalo/git/thesis/thesis-nltk/python/evaluation/word_probability.py", line 16, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  File "/Users/darrenkarlsapalo/.local/share/virtualenvs/thesis-nltk-QvwJevGq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from nltk.decorators import decorator, memoize
  File "/Users/darrenkarlsapalo/.local/share/virtualenvs/thesis-nltk-QvwJevGq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/decorators.py", line 23, in <module>
    sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if "nltk" not in p]
  File "/Users/darrenkarlsapalo/.local/share/virtualenvs/thesis-nltk-QvwJevGq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/decorators.py", line 23, in <listcomp>
    sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if "nltk" not in p]
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

How do I fix this? I just want my script to run but it's not continuing past the imports.

Answer (score 0):

## You can't iterate on a `None`.

The problem is descriptive enough: It is saying that it is trying to iterate through a non-iterable object. Specifically, the object you are trying to iterate is of the type `NoneType`: an instance of `None`.

In this specific scenario, the loop is defined as:

```
sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if "nltk" not in p]
```

In this example, each path denoted by `p` is iterated from the list `sys.path`. However, the string "nltk" could not be found in `p` on the case where `p = None`. Remember, `None` is not an iterable type. **There shouldn't be any `None` instances in the system path.**

### Where did the `None` come from?

Because we are working with the `sys.path` list, quickly inspecting the values of `sys.path` reveals that to make sense:

```
[None, '/Users/darrenkarlsapalo/git/thesis/thesis-nltk/python', '/Users/darrenkarlsapalo/.local/share/virtualenvs/thesis-nltk-QvwJevGq/lib/python36.zip', '/Users/darrenkarlsapalo/.local/share/virtualenvs/thesis-nltk-QvwJevGq/lib/python3.6', '/Users/darrenkarlsapalo/.local/share/virtualenvs/thesis-nltk-QvwJevGq/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Users/darrenkarlsapalo/.local/share/virtualenvs/thesis-nltk-QvwJevGq/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

At the head of the list, there is a `None` instance in the script. In that case, there was some piece of code that inserted `None` into the system path. By checking the source code again, it easily shows that we did not check whether the configuration file did indeed have a value.

#### Solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from os import environ

# Add python project root folder to python path
load_dotenv(find_dotenv(), override=True, verbose=False)
PYTHON_SCRIPTS_DIR = environ.get('PYTHON_SCRIPTS_DIR')
PROJECT_DIR = environ.get('PROJECT_DIR')

# CHECK FIRST WHETHER IT IS NOT NONE BEFORE ADDING

if PYTHON_SCRIPTS_DIR is not None:
    sys.path.insert(0, PYTHON_SCRIPTS_DIR)

from evaluation.word_probability import WordFrequencyCounter
```

Simply checking if the value is not `None` before adding to the system path fixes the problem.